# How do I handle RestAPI with RxJava?

Tags: java, rest, reactive-programming, rx-java2

The idea is that for `REST API` I have to return the updated data from a server: e.g., my server method should return `Single<Data>` but for DB it's have a method that return `Completable`, it results in the following code:

```
public Single<Player> updateShirtNumber(int number) {
    Player player = new Player();
    player.setShirtNumber(number);
    return playersDao.savePlayerCompletable(player).andThen(Single.just(player));
}
```

How can I avoid this `andThen(Single.just(player))` of things?

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid this unless you want/can change DB API (and, basically, do not use reactive approach in the first place, but in this case you don't need rx-java).

Think `savePlayerCompletable` as asynchronous method. Before you return the value from REST API you want to make sure that save operation finishes. That's what `andThen` does.